# ios 6.1 how to send a friend request to try my app

Tags: ios, facebook, request, invitation

i'm developing an ios app. Whit this app i can login whit a facebook user, thats works.

The second step is send on my feed a post likes "user has begin to user app.. ecc", thats works.

the next step is to invite friends to join my application. I do not want to publish a post on their wall, I want to send a "request" .. similar to trip advisor, my birthdays etc. .. how can I do?

i'm using a latest version of facebook ios sdk.. 3.1

thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use apprequests dialog:

```
[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

more about all params [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Comment: i'm sorry but i cannot find the method dialog:andParams:andDelegate facebook sdk 3.1. Can you help me?

Comment: it turn out to be deprecated, you can see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/dialog/

Comment: Is there a solution to send requests like "Marco invites you to try appName" in a transparent way? As "Tripadvisor", "my birthdays" etc. .. i wan't use a native dialog.. very very uncomfortable